Do I have to sever ties of Kinship with my non Muslim Family?
As-Salamu 'Alaykum brothers,
I have a pressing Question to ask in regards to the following verses of the Quran:

"O believers! Do not take your parents and siblings as trusted allies if they choose disbelief over belief. And whoever of you does so, they are the ˹true˺ wrongdoers" 9:23


"And We have commanded people to ˹honour˺ their parents. Their mothers bore them through hardship upon hardship, and their weaning takes two years. So be grateful to Me and your parents. To Me is the final return."31:14


"But if they pressure you to associate with Me what you have no knowledge of,1 do not obey them. Still keep their company in this world courteously, and follow the way of those who turn to Me ˹in devotion˺. Then to Me you will ˹all˺ return, and then I will inform you of what you used to do." 31:15

There are many other verses too that pertain to this matter. But my situation is that my Father is not a Muslim and he is a civil servant in the Airforce, and my Wife's Father is a polytheist (a Christian) and he works for a defense contractor. Doesn't this mean that I am not allowed to love them? there are so many other verses that talk about this, but I'm also confused because Allah also commands us to love our parents even if they are disbelievers.
Please help me figure this out.

Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and the StackExchange model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help].

As far as I can say:

We are commanded to behave with gratitude and kindness, showing all sorts of respect toward our parents, and not only our parents but also to anyone who has been kind to us. As Allah (AWJ) says, "هَلْ جَزَاءُ الْإِحْسَانِ إِلَّا الْإِحْسَانُ," which translates to "Is there any reward for good other than good?" [55:60]. This verse speaks to how we should behave, not necessarily how we should feel about others. For example, when Allah (AWJ) ordered Moses (PBUH) to go to Pharaoh and speak to him gently, it was not because Pharaoh deserved it, but rather for the opportunity it provided for him to repent and survive if he chose to do so. Allah (AWJ) commanded, "اذْهَبَا إِلَيٰ فِرْعَوْنَ إِنَّهُ طَغَيٰ، فَقُولَا لَهُ قَوْلًا لَيِّنًا لَعَلَّهُ يَتَذَكَّرُ أَوْ يَخْشَيٰ," which translates to "Go, both of you, to Pharaoh. Indeed, he has transgressed. And speak to him with gentle speech that perhaps he may be reminded or fear [Allah]." [20:43,44]. Being kind to our parents, obeying them in most, if not all, of their commands, respecting them, and never speaking to them with contempt or repelling them, but rather speaking to them with noble words, as Allah commands: "فَلَا تَقُلْ لَهُمَا أُفٍّ وَ لَا تَنْهَرْهُمَا وَ قُلْ لَهُمَا قَوْلًا كَرِيمًا," are all essential teachings. Loving others is an inner state, a kind of attraction, and the feelings of liking and disliking for a Muslim should be aligned with Allah. This concept is known as Tawalla and Tabarra (تولّیٰ و تبرّیٰ), which is a significant aspect of our faith. For instance, a companion of Imam Baqir (PBUH) once asked the Imam if his love for him held any value before Allah. The Imam (PBUH) affirmed that yes, religion is fundamentally about loving and hating for the sake of Allah: "هل الدین الا الحبّ و البغض؟"

As Muslims, we can love everyone, even animals and stones, if we remind ourselves that there is nothing but Allah and that nothing happens against His will. In a Persian poem by Sa'di (سعدی), we find a similar notion expressed: "عاشقم بر همه عالم که همه عالم از اوست," meaning "I am in love with the whole universe, for the whole universe is from Him." For example, after the Battle of Karbala, Ubaidullah ibn Ziyad mocked the household of the Holy Prophet (PBUH) as they were brought to Kufa as captives, saying, "What do you think of what Allah has done to your brother [Imam Hussain (PBUH)] and his companions?" Lady Zainab (PBUH), the daughter of Imam Ali (PBUH) and Lady Fatimah (PBUH), the granddaughter of the Holy Prophet (PBUH), responded, "I saw nothing but beauty" (ما رأیتُ الّا جَمیلاً). She emphasized that they are martyrs, and their sacrifice will not be forgotten. The truth will prevail, and the oppressors will face their consequences. This perspective is not just for ordinary people; it may explain why Ibrahim (PBUH) was so kind-hearted, never losing hope in guiding people and never tiring of their wrongdoings. For instance, when the Angels of Allah (PBUT) were sent to punish the people of Lut (PBUH), they first approached Ibrahim (PBUH), who tried to intercede for the people of Lut: "فَلَمَّا ذَهَبَ عَنْ إِبْرَاهِيمَ الرَّوْعُ وَ جَاءَتْهُ الْبُشْرَيٰ يُجَادِلُنَا فِي قَوْمِ لُوطٍ، إِنَّ إِبْرَاهِيمَ لَحَلِيمٌ أَوَّاهٌ مُنِيبٌ," which translates to "When fear had passed from (the mind of) Abraham and the glad tidings had reached him, he began to plead with us for Lut's people. For Abraham was, without doubt, forbearing (of faults), compassionate, and given to look to Allah." [11:74,75]. A better example is the Holy Prophet Muhammad (PBUHH) when Allah (AWJ) says, "لَقَدْ جَاءَكُمْ رَسُولٌ مِنْ أَنْفُسِكُمْ عَزِيزٌ عَلَيْهِ مَا عَنِتُّمْ حَرِيصٌ عَلَيْكُمْ بِالْمُؤْمِنِينَ رَءُوفٌ رَحِيمٌ," (Now hath come unto you a Messenger from amongst yourselves: it grieves him that ye should perish; ardently anxious is he over you [to be guided]; to the Believers is he most kind and merciful) [9:128], and "لَعَلَّكَ بَاخِعٌ نَفْسَكَ أَلَّا يَكُونُوا مُؤْمِنِينَ," (It may be thou frettest thy soul with grief, that they do not become Believers) [26:3], and "فَلَعَلَّكَ بَاخِعٌ نَفْسَكَ عَلَيٰ آثَارِهِمْ إِنْ لَمْ يُؤْمِنُوا بِهَذَا الْحَدِيثِ أَسَفًا," (Thou wouldst only, perchance, fret thyself to death, following after them, in grief, if they believe not in this Message) [18:6]. From this viewpoint, even if they fight against the enemies of Allah (AWJ) and kill someone, that is not the same as many of their companions taking part in the war. For instance, if they kill someone, it may be to rescue other people from going astray, and even to save those being killed from continuing their wrongdoings for a much longer time. There have been many great Muslims in history who have managed their lives to be merciful toward everyone. For example, Abul Hassan Kharaqani is famous for giving food to any poor person who asked for it, whether a believer or not, explaining his reason as, "Anyone who is given life by Allah will deserve to be given bread by me" (هر که نزد خالق به جان ارزد، نزد بوالحسن به نان ارزد).


Therefore, I suggest you express love to them, not out of hypocrisy or mere pretense, but with the intention that you love them to become Muslims, and save them not necessarily from a financial loss or a health-related issue that, God forbid, may trouble them for several years, but to save them from a danger whose duration is eternal, and no suffering in this world can be compared to even a moment of it. If you want to do them a real favor, save them. Isn't it the true love. If you love them wish the best for them, which should include here and the Hereafter. For this, you need their hearts, so be calm, nice, and loving, as Allah has ordered us: "وَ لَا تَسْتَوِي الْحَسَنَةُ وَ لَا السَّيِّئَةُ ادْفَعْ بِالَّتِي هِيَ أَحْسَنُ فَإِذَا الَّذِي بَيْنَكَ وَ بَيْنَهُ عَدَاوَةٌ كَأَنَّهُ وَلِيٌّ حَمِيمٌ," (And not equal are the good deed and the bad. Repel [evil] by that [deed] which is better; and thereupon the one whom between you and him is enmity [will become] as though he was a devoted friend) [41:34]. This is not something I have been very successful at personally, but I wish for you to be more successful than I have been.

Salaam,
I think you should never severe ties with people just because they are not Muslim. You may not agree with their point of view on religion, but Islam teaches us to be kind and loving to all, regardless of race, ethnicity, religion, etc.
I believe that by becoming closer to them, you can show them the beauty of Islam through your character, and maybe by doing so, they might even become more interested in Islam iA.
In the Qur'an, it mentions, “Worship Allah ˹alone˺ and associate none with Him. And be kind to parents, relatives, orphans, the poor, near and distant neighbours, close friends, ˹needy˺ travellers, and those ˹bondspeople˺ in your possession. Surely Allah does not like whoever is arrogant, boastful.” (An-Nisa' 4:36)
May Allah (swt) guide us all to the straight path. Ameen!
HOPE THAT HELPS!
-MuslimGap
